# How do I put a watchpoint in Xcode 4.5 ?

Tags: xcode

I need to put a breakpoint when someone changes some variable to some value.
I want to catch the exact moment this happens

Any hints please ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kneejerk reaction is to pause the program, add the watchpoint manually by typing:

> watch modify -c '(myVar == 23)'

(or whatever condition you want to evaluate) and then allow it to continue.

You can right click on a variable in the variable list and select 'Watch "variable name"' but there doesn't seem to be a way to make that conditional.

See the [LLDB Tutorial](http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html) for more on the command line-style interface to debugging; in particular you'll probably be interested in 'Setting Watchpoints' which is about halfway down.

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking for a solution like this. And to make it so you don't need to pause, set a breakpoint when the var is originally set.  Set 2 debugger actions in the breakpoint `watch set var myVar` then your `watch modify -c '(myVar == 23)'` then click the 'automatically continue' check mark.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a breakpoint inside of a code block which monitors the value of the variable:

```
// Some code that might change the value of the variable
    
if (theVar != lastValueOfVar) {
    NSLog(@"Value changed!"); // Add a breakpoint here
    lastValueOfVar = theVar;
}
```

From Apple's documentation on adding breakpoints to a project:

> To set a breakpoint, open a source-code file and click the gutter next to the line where you want execution to pause. When you add a breakpoint, Xcode automatically enables it. When an enabled breakpoint is encountered during execution, it will cause the program to pause.
>
> To disable a breakpoint, click the breakpoint icon in the gutter. Click the breakpoint icon again to re-enable the breakpoint.
>
> To turn off breakpoints, click the breakpoint button on the workspace toolbar. Click the button again to turn breakpoints back on.
>
> To move a breakpoint, drag it to a new location. To remove a breakpoint, drag it out of the gutter.

You can also use the hotkey "Command + Backslash" (`⌘\`) to add or remove a breakpoint.

Comment: Hi, I probably was not clear enough. I am not looking to put a breakpoint on the line of code. I want a watchpoint - if someone, somehwere, some time changes x theVar to value of 5 - i want it to break immediately